# Why are these functions assigned to objects with a "redundant" function name?

Tags: javascript

*Please feel free to reword the title if you think you have a better one.*

If you look through the source of [`bravo.js`](http://code.google.com/p/bravojs/source/browse/bravo.js) you'll notice the following on line 807.

```
module.declare = function main_module_declare(dependencies, moduleFactory)
```

What is the benefit of naming the function `main_module_declare`?

**Couldn't that just be written as the following?**

```
module.declare = function (dependencies, moduleFactory)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need to refer to the calling function in strict mode, it can be useful.

If you're like me and you don't give a toss for "stict mode", just use `arguments.callee` instead.

Comment: +1 You might also add that it eases debugging, since you'll get the function name in the stack trace.

Comment: For the record, these are called **named function expressions**. For a complete rundown of all its idiosyncrasies, I suggest you read [Named function expressions demystified](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/) (by [Juriy "kangax" Zaytsev](http://perfectionkills.com/)).

Comment: I only asked 3 minutes ago and I already got my answer plus 2 useful comments. Happy times. Have a good weekend peeps!

Comment: Do you plan on using the new module system in ECMAScript 6? If so, my understanding is that it will be strict-mode only.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest advantage of using an internal local variable for the function is that your module's code is indifferent as to whether the function is public or not. For example, if you want to turn a previously private function into a public function then just adding the `module.publicName = privateName` line is simpler then renaming all the intances of `privateName. This also applies the other way around if you want to remove a function from the public interface.

However, this doesn't apply to the particular situation you linked to, since the function isn't called again inside the module. That said, the comment mentions that `module.declare` could be overwritten so I guess there could be a reason for keeping a reference to the original function around somewhere.

Comment: `keeping a reference to the original function`. Where? `main_module_declare` [will not be available outside its function](http://jsfiddle.net/bmnxc/)?!

Comment: Sure, the `main_module_declare` name is module local. It could simply be a holdover from some previous version of the code where the function gets used or maybe something the auther does just as a habit. That said, I tried to answer the general case.

Comment: That's exactly my point. It's *not* a module local. It won't be available within that same model.

Comment: @JosephSilber: Looks like you are right. I guess I must have spent too much time lately using Lua :/ But just to be sure, could you run that fiddle in IE? I think in that case function expressions behave just as function statements as long as scoping goes.

Comment: IE makes a total mess out of this. I already linked to this on @missingno's answer, but here you go again: read through [**Named function expressions demystified**](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/). Trust me, it's worth it.